# How to handle File download dialog/popup in IE browser USING SELENIUM and C# /winium

Tags: c#, selenium, popup

How to handle File download dialog/popup in IE browser USING SELENIUM and C#

[image]

I have tried using winium and I can save file using save click but I have to close popup as well.
After download and open new window , I am not to switch last window due to this popup

Comment: you can avoid download popup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157